# C program: getenv return NULL in GDB/DDD

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I try to call getenv in my C code, this can return correct env string in terminal, while it returns NULL in GDB/DDD.

```
void main() {
  char * a = getenv("ANCHOR_STEM");
  if (strlen(a)>0)
    printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

The GDB/DDD is started from the same terminal.
Even I "show environment", this env exists.

Anyone any idea?

OS/Tools version info:
RHEL Linux hostname1 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 9 11:56:22 EDT 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.12
gcc (GCC) 6.3.0

Comment: Not related to the question but your return type of `main` is wrong. It must return `int`. And paremeter list is either `(void)` or `(int argc, char *argv[])`. Empty parameter list is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Even I "show environment", this env exists.

When GDB invokes your program, it starts a new *shell* to run this program in.

When the environment changes for the target program, most often this is the result of your shell initialization file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.kshrc`, etc.) changing the environment.

It is a really bad idea to change environment for non-interactive shells. [Documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html#Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f) on how to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, from GDB experts, I fixed this by "set startup-with-shell off". Must be something messed gdb in my .cshrc. BTW, I like mammut.

Answer (score 1):

include proper header files

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Treat warning as error.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've included those already, just not posting them here, sorry for the confusion..

Answer (score 0):

If getenv returns NULL it is because it does not find the environment variable. but still you have to be careful. This instruction `if (strlen(a)>0)` becomes illegal, if `getenv(....)`, fails. `getenv` sends back NULL and this instruction crash the program. It's better to test the **validity of the pointer** before to execute this line `if (strlen(a)>0)` -> which is not necessarily useful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char * a = getenv("ANCHOR_STEM");
    if( NULL != a ){
        (void)puts(a);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    (void)puts("none");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```